# Recursive solution to longest common substring not working

Tags: python, recursion, lcs, longest-substring

I am trying to get the longest common substring recursively but for some reason my code is not working.

```
def lcs(s, t):
    if not s or not t:
        return ''

    if s[0] is t[0]:
        return s[0] + lcs(s[1:], t[1:])

    a = lcs(s[1:], t)
    b = lcs(s, t[1:])

    return b if len(a) < len(b) else a


print(lcs("JHELLOIAHDS", "NHELLOOKSÇA"))

output>> HELLOS
```

The two input strings are "J**HELLO**IAHDS" and "N**HELLO**OKSÇA"
and the output should be **HELLO**.
What am I doing wrong and why am I getting "**HELLOS**" as output?

Comment: You seem to have a solution for the longest common _subsequence_ problem (characters in the common subsequence do not have to be contiguous), and for that, HELLOS is indeed the correct answer. If you need the longest common _substring_, where characters must be contiguous, you need a different algorithm.

Comment: @RayToal Pedantic paranoid side note: "HELLOS is indeed **a** correct answer" (HELLOA is another correct answer). Otherwise, +1, this is a trap when trying to solve the LCS problem: does S stand for substring or subsequence ?

Comment: A question to ask yourself in a case like this: what is the program doing when its behavior diverges from your expectations? Specifically, what is it doing when it reaches the end of the longest common substring?